# Linear independence of orthogonal vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {$v_1...v_k$} be a linearly independent subset of a vector space V. Let {$u_1...u_m$} be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V_{perpendicular}$. (So for example, $v \cdot x = 0)$. I want to prove now that the whole list {$v_1...v_k, u_1, ...u_m$} is linearly independent.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_1v_1+x_2v_2 +\cdots + x_kv_k + y_1u_1+y_2u_2+\cdots + y_mu_m = 0\implies x_1v_1+\cdots + x_kv_k = a = (-y_1)u_1+\cdots + (-y_m)u_m \in V_{\text{perp}}\implies a \in V \cap V_{perp}\implies a\cdot a = 0\implies a = 0\implies x_1=x_2=\cdots = x_k = 0 = y_1=y_2=\cdots = y_m$. Thus $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k, u_1, u_2,...,u_m\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors.